# What does this line mean in Java: boolean retry = id == 1;

Tags: java, syntax

I have been learning Java for a while now and still learning new syntax tricks and stuff. I came across this in Android source code:

```
boolean retry = id == 1;
```

What does it mean?

Comment: If you need to comment to clarify the question, please do so. The comments don't work so well for flaming, extended banter, or discerning the color of your socks.

Comment: Wow, this has over 80 total votes positive and negative. Why are people voting it down? It's clear, and it's on topic, and although it's a beginner question, it *would* be hard to google it. In order to find the answer you would have to know it was an operator precedence issue, and that's easily something a beginner might not yet understand. It's not a crime to be a beginner.

Comment: @Gus If it helps, this question was a bit controversial - at least enough to spark a [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166261/why-are-there-always-flamewars-over-questions-where-many-people-know-the-answer). That should explain some of the downvotes on both the question as well as the answers.

Comment: I always thought you had to put () around it like `boolean retry = (id == 1);` I guess that's for readability.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`retry` is `true` if `id` has the value 1, otherwise `retry` is `false`.

Answer (score 220):

`id == 1` is a boolean expression which is true if `id` equals `1`, and false otherwise.

`boolean retry = id == 1;` declares a boolean variable named `retry`, and assigns the value of the boolean expression `id == 1` to this variable.

So it declares a boolean variable which is true if `id == 1`, and false otherwise.

To make it a bit clearer, you might write it that way:

```
boolean retry = (id == 1);
```

Comment: I'd read it as a shorthand for `id == 1 ? true : false` where the `true` and `false` have become redundant

Answer (score 69):

It is the same as

```
boolean retry;
if (id == 1)
   retry = true;
else
   retry = false;
```

Answer (score 44):

`==`, which is the equality predicate, has a higher precedence than `=`, which is the assignment operator.

Therefore, `id == 1` is evaluated first and then its value (either true or false) is assigned to `retry`.

Answer (score 14):

The boolean retry gets the value of true if `id == 1`.

It's the same as:

```
boolean retry;
if (id == 1) {
    retry = true;
} else {
    retry = false;
}
```

Comment: Debug information is completely ignored (absent!) at runtime and thus should not make a difference.

Answer (score 6):

first the `id` is evaluated with 1, so presumably `id` is an `integer`.

After that, the value `retry` is assigned this evaluation, so if `id` is equal to 1, `retry` will become `true`, and for any other value of `id` `retry` will become `false`.

Answer (score 3):

This line creates a boolean variable and sets it to `true` if `id` is equal to 1 and `false` if it is not.

Answer (score 3):

It is acts like a ternary operation, `(x) ? true : false` in C, C++, C#, etc;

The similar syntax:

```
boolean retry = (id == 1)? true: false;
```

Or it can written another way:

```
boolean retry;
if (id == 1) {
    retry = true;
} else {
    retry = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I find that just using parens helps to clear up the confusion behind complex statements like this.

`boolean retry = (id == 1);` Makes much more sense to me. Here it's clear that `(id == 1)` is an expression being evaluated and the result is being assigned to `boolean retry`

Comment: It is a basic concept that a Java programmer should know that `==` has precedence over `=`.

Comment: Not complex as in complicated. I meant complex as in a statement composed of multiple operations (evaluation, assignment). Compound if you prefer?

Answer (score 2):

It is a way of defining a boolean variable.

When `id` is `1`, the value of `retry` will be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

`retry` assigns an expression which will be either true or false as `retry` is a `boolean`.
Further, `==` will be solved first and then it will be assigned to `retry`.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to see whats happening if you look at it like this:

```
boolean retry = (id == 1);
```

So basically it checks if id equals 1, and then assigns the result to the variable retry.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically the same as `retry = (id == 1)`.  It is evaluating the boolean expression, and assigning it to `retry`.

Answer (score 1):

The Boolean variable `retry` will get value `0` or `1` depending on whether the expression `id==1` returns `true` or `false`.

If value of `id` is `1`, then `id==1` will correspond to `true`, thus `retry=1`.

And if value of `id` is `0`, then `id==1` will correspond to `false`, thus `retry=0`.

Please note that `==` is a comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

I will base my response on the assumption that **id** is an int hence the comparison against 1 is proper and a compilation error is not in place. 
[==](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) is the equality operator in java as described in section [15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) of the JLS. Being a boolean operator, == will output a [boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.5) value.
[=](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) is the java's assignment operator, in this particular case it's the [compound assignment operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) having the following syntax:

> boolean f = (op1 op op2)

In translation = assigns the output value of the `(op1 op op2)` operation to the left operand, in this case **f**.

Looking back to your sample, the output of `id == 1` (true if id has the value 1, false otherwise) is assigned to **retry**.

To conclude in plain english, your sample has the following meaning: *Retry as long as id has the value 1*.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.int id = 1;
  boolean retry = id == 1;
```

which means `retry = true;`.

```
2.int id = 2;
  boolean retry = id == 1;
```

which means `retry = false;`.

Simplification id == 1 can be consider as

```
if ( id == 1 ){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can write just like this,then it will be understood easily,do you think
so? Last, thanks you for giving the chance to answer the question!

```
boolean retry = (id == 1);
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be vague and confusing. Don't write your comments along with your answer.